# Substring of a specific pattern in different positions

Tags: python, pandas, split, extract

I have a column in my dataframe where all the equipment used for a test are in codes and grouped together.

```
data = [{'Equipment': 'C-FDO:ER09999,M-GEP:IO09765,P-EE047777,P-PP04757,P-IR07086,P-EE2222,P-ER20000,tEE3-ERE:CC046846'},
        {'Equipment': 'C-FDO:ER09999,M-GEP:IO09765,tEE3-ERE:CC04647, P-CC07777,P-PP047557,P-IR07086,P-EE2223,P-ER20000'},
        {'Equipment': 'tEE3-ERE:CC04648, C-FDO:ER7809999,M-GEP:IO09765,P-PP07777,P-PP04757,P-IR07086,P-EE2224,P-ER20000'},
        {'Equipment': 'C-FDO:ER09999,M-GEP:IO09765,P-PP07777, P-PP04757, tEE3-ERE:CC04649, P-ER01465,P-EE22250,P-ER201212000'}]
```

I need to get the **4th occurrence of the "P-" equipment** and **all the occurrences of the "tEE3-ERE"** equipment per line, but I can't do this by position slicing, since they are shuffled.

I tried to [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by comma and some [regex](https://regex101.com/) through [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), but it didn't work as I have more than one "P-".
So I don't need any other occurrence of P- (but 4th) nor other equipment like "C-FDO" and "M-GEP".

**Expected result:**

```
P-EE2222  tEE3-ERE:CC046846
P-EE2223  tEE3-ERE:CC04647
P-EE2224  tEE3-ERE:CC04648
P-EE22250 tEE3-ERE:CC04649

P-      tEE3-ERE
EE2222  CC046846
EE2223  CC04647
EE2224  CC04648
EE22250 CC04649
```

Comment: This data structure seems ill suited for its apparent purpose. Can you get whatever generates this porridge to produce a more useful format?

Comment: @tripleee Unfortunately, I don't have access to the entire database, not even to make SQL queries/selects. I also don't work in data extraction, so I'm having to adapt myself to the dataframe they give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), filtering on the match number (3 for the 4th), and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with the extracted values for `tEE3-ERE`:

```
out = (df['Equipment'].str.extractall('P-([^,]+)')
       .query('match == 3').droplevel('match')
       .rename(columns={0: ('P-')})
       .join(df['Equipment'].str.extractall('tEE3-ERE:([^,]+)')[0]
             .droplevel('match').rename('tEE3-ERE'))
      )
```

Output:

```
        P-  tEE3-ERE
0   EE2222  CC046846
1   EE2223   CC04647
2   EE2224   CC04648
3  EE22250   CC04649
```

Alternative output:

```
out = (df['Equipment'].str.extractall('(P-[^,]+)')
       .query('match == 3').droplevel('match')
       .join(df['Equipment'].str.extractall('(tEE3-ERE:[^,]+)')[0]
             .droplevel('match').rename(1))
      )

           0                  1
0   P-EE2222  tEE3-ERE:CC046846
1   P-EE2223   tEE3-ERE:CC04647
2   P-EE2224   tEE3-ERE:CC04648
3  P-EE22250   tEE3-ERE:CC04649
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
regp=r'(?:P\-\w+.*?){3}P\-(?P<P_>\w+)'
regte=r'tEE3-ERE:(?P<tEE3_ERE>\w+)'
dfp=df['Equipment'].str.extract(regp)
dfte=df['Equipment'].str.extract(regte)
result=dfp.join(dfte)
```

or:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
regp=r'(?:P\-\w+.*?){3}P\-(?P<P_>\w+)'
regte=r'tEE3-ERE:(?P<tEE3_ERE>\w+)'
result=pd.concat(map(df['Equipment'].str.extract,[regp,regte]),axis=1)
```